# Plotting roots of a non polynomial function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'd like to plot the solutions of a function f(y)=k, when f(y) is non polynomial. This is the Mathematica script I have produced so far:

```
P = 1; a = 1;
f[y_] = ArcCos[P*Sin[Sqrt[y]*a]/(Sqrt[y]*a) + Cos[Sqrt[y]*a]]/a ;

roots[k_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[f[y] == k, {y, 0.1, 0.5}];

dataRoots = {roots[#], #} & /@ Range[0.01, \[Pi]/a, 0.01];

Show[ListPlot[dataRoots, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]]
```

Where I have provided two starting (trial) values for y, 0.1 and 0.5. The problem is that the resulting plot is empty. Is there any smarter way to easily find and plot the roots?

Comment: Your function has complex values in that interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[k == f[y], {y, 0, 4}, {k, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {y,k}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works although it does not plot the negative k part...

Comment: @ cipper: Because `f[y]>0` there exists no negative solution k!

Comment: you are right (duh!), I must put `f[y] == Abs[k]` to show the full plot. Thank you again.